# Schedule a script to run at midnight to append current date to sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I implement a script that each day at midnight will add a row to a sheets document, with the current date in it, below whatever the bottom cell is that is full?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Sheet.appendRow()`, like this:

```
function appendDateRowToSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const timestampFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
  const timezone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  const dateString = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestampFormat);
  sheet.appendRow([dateString]);
}
```

Create a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to run the function.